# Htaccess how to mod_deflate javascript file ending in suffix .js?ver=3.1

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, google-pagespeed, mod-deflate

I use mod_deflate to speed my site up. I have one JavaScript file that will not deflate (I believe because it ends `.js?ver=3.1` rather than `.js`). Below is my `.htaccess` code:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml
#The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".(xml|txt|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=904800, proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the file is not external?

Comment: No the file is on my server - part of the website template.

Comment: Could you include your entire `.htaccess` file, it looks incomplete.

Comment: Btw, the URL ends in `.js?ver=3.1`, the _file_ is still `.js` - so this should not cause a problem for Apache. Any reason you're not using `AddOutputFilterByType` for `js` and `css` files as well?

Comment: I edited to add the rest of the htaccess. No reason I am not using AddOutputFilterByType. I just tried now, same result.

Comment: Just to clarify, all other `.js` and `.css` files do deflate OK?

Comment: Yes all others deflate.